# Cross-site publishing; how to create and crawl related content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

Using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise for a Publishing site.

This blog post on [cross-site publishing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/02/13/how-to-set-up-a-product-centric-website-in-sharepoint-server-2013/) contains the following screenshot:

[image]

It's a Product details page that contains related content such as "Customer reviews". I assume the customer reviews are stored in a separate list given the one-to-many relationship with products.

As far as I'm aware the Content Search Web Part can't perform "joins", so how would this page pull in related content? and how would the page be displayed in search results based on the related content e.g.

A user searches for a term that is not contained within the product itself, but is contained within a customer review about the product.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I'm aware the Content Search Web Part can't perform "joins",
>   so how would this page pull in related content? and how would the page
>   be displayed in search results based on the related content

You can create a separate list which shares product id or a listitemid and include customer reviews as a field for the different products. Then search in that list by product id and review specific managed property.

You can use the same list to try this out as well.